# is there some way to execute vbs through python like os.system

Tags: python, vbscript

I am working on a Project but I need to run vbs code but I use python
so is there a way to execute vbs code? without doing os.system("Script.vbs")
Like where we use cmd using os.system()

```
os.system("echo Command Prompt && pause")
```

example

```
os.vbscript("CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is with a subprocess. Especially for Windows systems this way is very elegant. You can even use the VBS output for further processing

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'More output'],
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
stdout, stderr
```